# В рецепции или на рецепции?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить: *в рецепции* или *на рецепции?*

Answer (score 2):

> **Рецепия** (лат. receptio принятие, прием)
> 1) заимствование и приспособление данным обществом социологических и культурных форм, возникших в другой стране или в другую эпоху;
> Р. римского права - усвоение в Средние Века странами Зап. Европы римского права;
> 2) физиол. осуществляемое рецепторами восприятие и преобразование энергии раздражителей в нервное возбуждение.

Новый словарь иностранных слов, 2009

В обоих случаях предлог "на" обозначает, что сказывается на процессе, а "в" - внутренние особенности процесса.

Если вы имеете в виду стойку администрации в отеле, то можете считать меня пуристом, но я считаю что по-русски её правильно называть именно так, для иностранцев можно продублировать надпись на английском.

Comment: Согласна. Хотя "рецепция" уже лучше, чем "рецеПШН"

Comment: А мне кажется, что еще хуже.

Comment: publication -публикация, information - информация, 
reception - рецепция